Howto use own API key in VS-Code GitHub-Copilot
GitHub-Copilot is now free in VS-Code, but:
As a develper
I want to use my own API key
So that I have control over the model
Is it possible to use my own OpenAI-API or Perplexity-API keys?
The Documentation is not conclusive here.

please don't make us click off-site to get information about the question. [ask].
